# vim gf with resource://

Tags: path, keyboard-shortcuts, vim

I'm working on some Firefox extensions and I'm trying to set up my vim to open modules using the gf keys.

An inclusion looks like this:
Components.utils.import("resource://grwmodules/EventProvider.jsm", scope);

which should be modules/EventProvider.jsm

I created a file to set up the environment. Here is what I have so far:

```
function! s:GetModuleName(name)
  let l:output = a:name
  if(a:name =~ "^resource://grwmodules")
    let output = substitute(a:name, "resource://grwmodules", "modules", "")
  endif
  return l:output
endfunction

function! GetGrwFNName(name)
  let l:output = s:GetModuleName(a:name)
  return l:output
endfunction
set includeexpr=GetGrwFNName(v:fname)
set isf+=:
set include=Components.utils.import("resource[:/]\+.\+")
```

After added the isf+=: line, the :checkpath command works. But when I press gf on the file, the vim opens a new file which name would be resource://grwmodules/EventProvider.jsm. So it looks like when I press the gf it doesn't convert the name using GetGrwFNName.

Any ideas?

Comment: `'includeexpr'` is local to the buffer so it may be best to put this in `~/.vim/after/jsm.vim`. Assuming the `filetype` is `jsm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to create an autocommand `FileReadCmd`, e.g. what netrw has for http:// urls:

```
:verbose au FileReadCmd
```

HTH